# gwt export to file

Tags: gwt

i have a problem with gwt application. i have an array of strings in the client application and i want to export it to a file, but it isn't probably possible so i have to use servlet, right? but i don't really know how.

Comment: Where and why do you need to save the array of strings? Do you need to export it to csv or some other format so that a client can download it? Or do you need to persist it somewhere so that your app can use it on subsequent requests? ...maybe some other reason?

Comment: Exaclly, i need to export it to txt or gpx format and client could download it.These strings are points taken from the map used in my application.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite unfortunate, given the advance of browser applications, that data produced by such applications cannot be saved by the user locally, but instead has to make e round trip to the server. It would be really helpful, I think, to adopt the data scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for such cases, and not only for images, which has proved itself quote useful. If this scheme is adopted a GWT app could build a link  and provide the data to be saved as part of the href attribute of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide on [How to Call a Servlet in GWT](http://zawoad.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-call-servlet-in-gwt.html).

Alternatively, use the [GWT HTTP client](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html) to send a GET or POST request to the servlet.

Answer (score -1):

In this case using servlet is a good idea or maybe RPC is better. What do you think? So far I wrote a separate servlet that writes an array of strings to a file. But I don't know how to connect to the gwt project. Will this created file be HttpServletResponse response in this case?